# Get array of properties from Array of Objects in Java script / Type script

Tags: javascript

I have below array how to get list of names where the age is greater than 18.
so the out put should be: `["Anna", "Bob"]`

```
  friends = [{
  name: 'Anna',
  books: ['Bible', 'Harry Potter'],
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'Bob',
  books: ['War and peace', 'Romeo and Juliet'],
  age: 26
}, {
  name: 'Alice',
  books: ['The Lord of the Rings', 'The Shining'],
  age: 18
}]
```

I have tried below

```
let names = friends.map((item) => {if (item.age > 18){ return item.name}});
```

but i got below output

```
["Anna", "Bob", undefined]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let friends = [{
  name: 'Anna',
  books: ['Bible', 'Harry Potter'],
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'Bob',
  books: ['War and peace', 'Romeo and Juliet'],
  age: 26
}, {
  name: 'Alice',
  books: ['The Lord of the Rings', 'The Shining'],
  age: 18
}];

let ans = friends.reduce((acc, val) => (val.age > 18 && acc.push(val.name),acc), []);

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Here is a little tip, instead of your tenary that's returning a useless `""`, you could use a logical and, `&&`.. eg.. `val.age > 18 && acc.push(val.name);`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before `Array.map()` since `map` always returns a value and you'll get `undefined` if you don't specify `return` statement. For 3-elements array there's always going to be 3-elements result.

```js
let friends = [{
  name: 'Anna',
  books: ['Bible', 'Harry Potter'],
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'Bob',
  books: ['War and peace', 'Romeo and Juliet'],
  age: 26
}, {
  name: 'Alice',
  books: ['The Lord of the Rings', 'The Shining'],
  age: 18
}]

let result = friends.filter(f => f.age > 18).map(f => f.name);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `undefined` as the last item in `names` array because `map` function is used to transform each item in the array it is called on and then return each transformed value.

If you call it on an array of length 3, `map` function will return an array of same length. Since you are only returning those names from `map` function where age is greater than 18, last object where age is not greater than 18, you are not transforming it and returning its name property, so you get `undefined`.

One way to achieve the desired result is to use `filter` function to filter out the object where age is not greater than 18 and then call `map` function on that filtered array.

In above approach, you code will first iterate over the `friends` array and then iterate over the filtered array.

You can achieve desired result and iterate over `friends` array only once using `reduce` function

```js
const friends = [{
  name: 'Anna',
  books: ['Bible', 'Harry Potter'],
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'Bob',
  books: ['War and peace', 'Romeo and Juliet'],
  age: 26
}, {
  name: 'Alice',
  books: ['The Lord of the Rings', 'The Shining'],
  age: 18
}];

const res = friends.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.age > 18 && acc.push(curr.name), acc), []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let friends = [{   name: 'Anna',   books: ['Bible', 'Harry Potter'],   age: 21 }, {   name: 'Bob',   books: ['War and peace', 'Romeo and Juliet'],   age: 26 }, {   name: 'Alice',   books: ['The Lord of the Rings', 'The Shining'],   age: 18 }]

let ages = friends.filter((friends) => friends.age>18)

let finalResult = ages.map(fun => ages.name)

console.log(finalResult)
```

**Use Array.filter()**